# Magento 2 Product Detail Page Not Loading

Tags: magento2, backend, frontend-error

`Magento 2` products details page is not loading in Admin and frontend.

`Screenshot here:` http://prntscr.com/it1ur3 .

Things I have already done

1. Grant permissions
2. Re-index
3. Compile
4. Flush cache

Comment: Can you check what errors are posting in log files.@P.Paul

Comment: Enable developer mode `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`

Comment: Can you please check javascript error in console?

Comment: seems some sort of js error. just change to developer and do a force deploy.

Answer (score 0):

you have to deploy site with following command ::

php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: Sorry. I haven't seen your reply earlier. The problem was already solved. But thank you for supporting.